# Can android.permission_group be used

Tags: android, android-permissions

I want to make an application that uses permissions related to Messages. One way of taking permission is mentioning all required permissions separately like below:

```
<uses-permission android:name=”android.permission.Receive_SMS”/>
<uses-permission android:name=”android.permission.Send_SMS”/>
<uses-permission android:name=”android.permission.Read_SMS”/>
<uses-permission android:name=”android.permission.Write_SMS”/>
```

I want to ask that instead of mentioning these permissions separately, can I use `permission_group` i.e to take all permissions related to messages, like below:

```
<uses-permission android:name=”android.permission_group.MESSAGES”/>
```

Comment: Not according to the documentation for `<uses-permission>`: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-permission-element.html Also note that your values are wrong, as it is `RECEIVE_SMS`, not `Receive_SMS`, and so on.

Comment: Then what is the use of these groups anyway ??

Comment: Quoting the documentation for `<permission-group>`: "Members of a group are presented together in the user interface". https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/permission-group-element.html Here, "user interface" refers to things like the permission confirmation screen when an app is installed on the device.

Comment: I do not mean `<permission-group>` tag. I mean android native permission groups mentioned at [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission_group.html). Can I use this instead of permissions mentioned at [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html)

Comment: "I do not mean <permission-group> tag" -- the "android native permission groups" are defined by `<permission-group>` tags, in the platform manifest: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/res/AndroidManifest.xml Hence, the documentation for `<permission-group>` would appear to be valid.

Comment: Got my answer. Thanks alot